# Three tables difference query

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables: `Names`, `ToDo`, `TasksDone`. Their columns structure is below:

```
'Names' table:
    Name (nvarchar)
    Status (nvarchar)

'ToDo' table:
    Task (nvarchar)
    Date (smalldatetime)
    Name (nvarchar)

'TasksDone' table:
    TaskStatus (nvarchar)
    Date (smalldatetime)
    Name (nvarchar)
```

```
'Names' table:
Name    | Status
John    | Available 
Ryan    | Available 
Sean    | NotAvailable

'ToDo' table:
Task      | Date       | Name
Washing   | 01.01.2012 | John   
Cleaning  | 03.01.2012 | Ryan
Washing   | 04.01.2012 | Sean   

'TasksDone' table:
TaskStatus| Date       | Name
Done      | 01.01.2012 | John   
Done      | 02.01.2012 | Ryan
NotDone   | 02.01.2012 | Sean
```

I want to get all the `Name` from the `Names` table with `Status='Available'` which are not found in `ToDo` and `TasksDone` tables on a given day (date).

Comment: Make an effort and try it and show us what you have tried so far, thats the only way you can learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (YOUR_DATE is your Date and must be replace)

```
SELECT
    n.Name
FROM Names n
LEFT OUTER JOIN ToDo t
    ON t.Name = n.Name
    AND t.Date = YOUR_DATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN TasksDone td
    ON td.Name = n.Name
    AND td.Date = YOUR_DATE
WHERE
    n.Status = 'Available'
    AND t.Name IS NULL
    AND td.Name IS NULL
```